# DatePicker databinding sets default value to 1/1/0001 WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, data-binding, datepicker

I have a DatePicker bound to a DataTime within an object, and at run time, instead of the string "Select a Date" in DatePicker, "1/1/0001" is shown, making it hard to use the actual calendar.  I did not have a problem when I was binding DatePicker with a string, but changing it to a DateTime did this.  Please let me know how this works.  This is what I have so far:

In XAML I have:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9" Name="dueDateBox" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
        <Binding Path="DueDate" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <my:DateRangeRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
</DatePicker>
```

In the C# I have:

```
public DateTime DueDate
{
    get { return dueDate; }
    set
    {
        if (DueDate != null) || !DueDate.Equals(value))
        {
            dueDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DueDate");
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a dependency property set, not sure if this is playing a part:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DueDateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DueDate", typeof(DateTime),
        typeof(UpdateJobDialog), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would probably help to use DateTime? instead of DateTime, since DateTime is not nullable, you are setting to the default value of 1/1/0001, rather than null which would result in the please select a date message you are used to.

```
public DateTime? DueDate
{
    //Need to change the type of the private variable as well
    get { return dueDate; }
    set
    {
        if (DueDate != null) || !DueDate.Equals(value))
        {
            dueDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DueDate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works if the field is null-able.  what if the field is not-null ?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't connecting `DueDateProperty` dependency property to your `DueDate` property. Try this instead:

```
public DateTime DueDate
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DueDateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DueDateProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem with binding date property that had a null value to a datepicker. No matter what I tried the value displayed was 01/01/0001. I finally fixed this by setting up a second property as a string specifically to bind to the xaml datepicker, and if my date was null then I return string.empty

This solved it... (code in VB)

```
Public Property ClosedDateDTP() As String
    Get
        If _closedDate = Nothing Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Return _closedDate.ToString
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value = Nothing Then
            _closedDate = Nothing
        Else
            _closedDate = CDate(value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

XAML datepicker code...

```
        <DatePicker x:Name="dtpClosedDate"
                SelectedDate="{Binding ClosedDateDTP, Mode=TwoWay}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="284,120,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
    </DatePicker>
```