# DatePicker databinding sets default value to 1/1/0001 WPF c# for a Not-Nullable date

Tags: wpf, datagrid

This is an "extension" question to the 1/1/0001 question:
[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146977/datepicker-databinding-sets-default-value-to-1-1-0001-wpf-c-sharp)

The original Q. Solution - 
To set the DateTime field to be nullable (DateTime?) solves this problem.

What is the solution  when the underlying field must be **NOT NULL ?**

(In that case, the binding cause the DataGrid column Date Time Picker to set it's self to 01/01/0001)

The Actual Entity in my case is generate by Entity Framework 6.

Comment: why not simply add validation? in your viewmodel use nullable datetime and when you want go to your model validate your date.

Comment: My problem is when adding a new line to the grid. when I update I check everything. but in a new line, I get the cell with 01/01/0001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct me if I am wrong. You fill your not-null-field with 01/01/0001 to indicate that it's null. (not recommended)

One solution is to define a converter. something like this :

```
public class NotNullDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var aDateTime = value as DateTime;
        if (aDateTime != null && aDateTime == .... )
            return null

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can define a static field to a converter to use it later in xaml.

```
public static NotNullDateConverter NotNullDateConverter = new NotNullDateConverter();
```

Then you use this convert inside your xaml for binding:

```
SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DueDate, Converter={x:Static local:SomeClass.NotNullDateConverter}}"
```

Comment: i don't fill it, the grid does... because it is not null.. it's set's the minimum value...

Comment: I knew that you had to do it this way. but what about the converter did you try it? it should solve the problem.

Comment: Will try in a few hours and report back

Comment: @Ashi: Not quite, though I admit they're similar.  I wanted to show how to use the converter as a static resource rather than from code-behind.

Comment: @NielW: you are right. Thanks for participating your ideas. I don't know how things work here. I am being active here just recently.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, so I wrote a converter that could weed out non-dates.

```
//Just weeds out non-dates. Format should be set with StringFormat on the binding
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        if (date != null && date.Year != 1)
        {
            return date;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I use it like so:

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
    <logic:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter"/>
</DataTemplate.Resources>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastUpdateTime, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss}, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work if you actually care about dates in year 1.  :-)